# How to determine if this is a new App launch or old one?

Tags: android, android-context, android-library

How to determine if this is a new App launch or old one from the library from the dependencies of the App? Library has access to App Context. Are there any UID that changes each App launch?

I'm talking about a 1st app launch while a phone is awaken, not the 1st launch ever.

Comment: What exactly you mean by *1st app launch while a phone is awaken, not the 1st launch ever*?